# Multiple Security Policies in Axis2

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, ws-security, rampart

I am trying to apply one WS Security policy for each operation in services.xml file. This way I can implement the authorization as well, as Rampart do not support authorization. I can implement a handler for each set of operations for authorization.

I get below exception -

> [ERROR] InvalidSecurity org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: InvalidSecurity
>     at
>   org.apache.rampart.handler.PostDispatchVerificationHandler.invoke(PostDispatchVerificationHandler.java:152)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)  at
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)  at
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)    at
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:168)   at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)